Dystopian romance book in which the world is split in two, with the rich side being called the Class
I'm looking for a dystopian romance book I read a couple of years ago.
The world is split in two; the rich are called the Class and I can't remember the name of the poor side. There is like a chain link fence separating them. The main character is from the Class side and runs away because she's forced to marry. The main male character is called Rage.

A chain link fence doesn't sound like an especially secure way to split a society down the middle

Tbf it wasn’t how the two main characters meet is that the male one climbs it to steal from the class side

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/114403.The_Guardians - Rob, not Rage. "The County", not "The Class", but a decent match.
